# Semi-accept answers

Tags: feature-request

I've noticed that the system user 'Community' bumps up un-accepted questions quite often. Now, the issue is that most of these questions have satisfactory answers, and the OP may even have indicated as in the comments that the question has been satisfactorily answered (example: [How do I find the tension in additional strings in this problem?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/19000/how-do-i-find-the-tension-in-additional-strings-in-this-problem)). The OP just hasn't clicked the accept button (maybe it wasn't obvious to them?)

These questions clutter up the main page and push new questions downwards.

I propose that moderators(or xyz rep users) be allowed to semi-accept an answer that is most probably correct, it just hasn't been accepted by an inactive OP. The semi accept shouldn't have a rep bonus, its only functionality is to stop Community from bumping. Maybe we can have a flag option for semi accept.

Thoughts?

Comment: I believe that this is a new variant of a suggest that has been shot down on the mother meta many, many times. You get credit for thinking of a new version, and it may be different enough to be interesting on the mother meta. I'm going to ask some other moderators to weigh in and we may migrate it.

Comment: Related suggestion: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11576/

Answer (score 6):

Notes from other moderators.

- Shog9 tells me that it is already the case that questions with upvoted answers get the low rate of Community bumps, not the high rate.

Comment: Its not necessary that the answer will have any upvotes. This happens a lot on homework questions--the answer is too simple to get any upvotes. Thanks for asking around, though.

Comment: I think the best thing to do with those if flag them for possible deletion. They are off-topic, after all. I've been in the habit of not deleting them instantly because nice people sometimes leaves hints in the comments.

Comment: Yeah, that's there as well. Though homework isn't the only source of such questions. I've noticed that it barely brings up any good questions, just boringish ones with simple answers. Only omce or twice have I seen it bump a good and/or unanswered question.

Comment: The Community bump feature is rather more interesting on sites with a big archive and a lot of users. It is likely to be more useful on Physics in another year or so. It works pretty well on Stack Overflow and Super User.